# How do I get AccessKey or AcceleratorKey to work in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I have some buttons in my Silverlight 2 app that I want the user to access from the keyboard.

If I understand correctly, I should be able to use AutomationProperties.AccessKey. For example:

```
<Button Content="Close" Name="btnClose" AutomationProperties.AccessKey="CTRL+Q" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

But I can't get this to work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SL doesn't handle the AccessKey (or AcceleratorKey) properties directly. This means you still have to trap KeyDown events in your application and activate functionality there. From what I can tell the only advantage of setting the AccessKey/AcceleratorKey properties is to notify your intent to screen readers and the like.